# IF Else with AND, OR in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the excel data in the below format:

```
severity    Type    Overview    Classification  Result
critical    defect  closed      Fix             Good
serious     enhance no change   no fix          Low
Medium      defect  no change   no fix          Low
Low         enhance closed      fix             Poor
critical    defect  Duplicate   fix             Good
Medium      defect  Duplicate   fix             Low
Low         defect  Duplicate                   Poor
```

I have written the formula to calculate the result, But i couldn't execute due my bad knowledge in excel. Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the conditions:

```
 Severity           Type               Overview     Classifcation       Result
Citical/Serious     Defect/Enhance      Closed          Fix                 Good
                    Defect/Enhance      Closed          No fix              Poor
                    Defect/Enhance      Closed          Updated             Low
                    Defect/Enhance      Duplicate       No fix              poor


Medium/low          Defect/Enhance      closed          No fix              Low
                    Defect/Enhance      Duplicate       No fix              Poor
```

Comment: this is all 1 formula ? 3 lines ?

Comment: Please explain the conditions with words or with readable pseudocode. It's not obvious what are conditions and results and what precendence they should have from your code.

Comment: @NicolaiEhemann I want to calculate the "Result" cell from the data provided in the "severity", "Type", "Overview" and "classification".

Comment: @ShaiRado yes it is one formula.

Comment: can you provide a list of scenarios and what their result would be. Like, what conditions would make result good?

Comment: @louis Yes, but what exactly are the conditions and desired results? That is not obvious from your code.

Comment: @davidhu2000 Here are the condtions:Severity   Type    Overview  Classifcation  Result
Citical/Serious  Defect/Enhance  Closed   Fix     Good
     Defect/Enhance  Closed   No fix    Poor
     Defect/Enhance  Closed   Updated    Low
     Defect/Enhance  Duplicate  No fix    poor

     
Medium/low   Defect/Enhance  closed   No fix    Low
     Defect/Enhance  Duplicate  No fix    Poor

Comment: @NicolaiEhemann I have updated the conditions

Comment: First of all, when you do formulas in Excel, you need to use cells reference instead of names. If your severity is in column A, you will use A2 (or whatever line number you are at) in your ifs/and/or

Comment: @Oligg yes, I have to use cell number, but i have given the example.

Comment: If you have a table of all the possible combinations and their expected outcome just use INDEX/MATCH to test and return the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have your data in Range A1:D8, where your first line is the header.
You can use this (ugly) formula which does exactly what you described in your conditions table:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A2="Critical",A2="Serious"),OR(B2="Defect",B2="Enhance")),IF(C2="closed",IF(D2="Fix","Good",IF(D2="No fix","Poor",IF(D2="Updated","Low"))),IF(AND(C2="Duplicate",D2="No"),"poor","No match")),
IF(AND(OR(A2="Medium",A2="Low"),OR(B2="Defect",B2="Enhance")),IF(AND(C2="closed",D2="No fix"),"Low","No match"),IF(AND(C2="duplicate",D2="No fix"),"Poor")))
```

The trick is to use the else condition as an elseif.. and when you have alot is makes it really hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

It is not nice, but the solution to the conditions defined in your last table is like this:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A2="Critical";A2="Serious");C2="Closed";D2="Fix");"Good";IF(AND(OR(A2="Critical";A2="Serious");C2="Closed";D2="No fix");"Poor";IF(AND(OR(A2="Critical";A2="Serious");C2="Closed";D2="Updated");"Low";IF(AND(OR(A2="Critical";A2="Serious");C2="Duplicate";D2="No fix");"Poor";IF(AND(OR(A2="Medium";A2="Low");C2="Closed";D2="No fix");"Low";IF(AND(OR(A2="Medium";A2="Low");C2="Duplicate";D2="No fix");"Poor";"Undefined"))))))
```

Written in a more readable, multiline fashion (I'm not sure this will survive copy&paste):

```
=IF(AND(OR(A2="Critical";A2="Serious");C2="Closed";D2="Fix");"Good";
   IF(AND(OR(A2="Critical";A2="Serious");C2="Closed";D2="No fix");"Poor";
     IF(AND(OR(A2="Critical";A2="Serious");C2="Closed";D2="Updated");"Low";
       IF(AND(OR(A2="Critical";A2="Serious");C2="Duplicate";D2="No fix");"Poor";
         IF(AND(OR(A2="Medium";A2="Low");C2="Closed";D2="No fix");"Low";
           IF(AND(OR(A2="Medium";A2="Low");C2="Duplicate";D2="No fix");"Poor";
             "Undefined"
           )
         )
       )
     )
   )
 )
```

As you can see, any combination you have not covered will result in `"Undefined"`. You could probably combine some of the conditions, but that will not necessarily be more readable.

The niced solution would perhaps be a complete lookup table in a separate sheet with CHOOSE() and VLOOKUP()...